# `ng2-translate` - always sets with `english` other language not setting

Tags: angular, angular-translate, angular-i18n

I am using `ng2-translate` - for translation. but when i change the language still the translate uses the `en`. but I am looking for `fr`, my default not loading at all. here is my code :

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  data:any;

  constructor(private router:Router, private route: ActivatedRoute, private translate:TranslateService ) {

    translate.addLangs(["fr","en"]);
    translate.setDefaultLang("fr");//french not loading!!

    let browserlang = translate.getBrowserLang();
    translate.use(browserlang.match(/fr|en/) ? browserlang:"fr");

    console.log('browserlang', browserlang );

  }

}
```

my template:

```
<h1>{{ 'home.title' | translate }} </h1>
```

Comment: What is the log message of `browserlang`?

Comment: always `en` i am getting in the console

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add a line to set current language to French:

```
constructor(private router:Router, private route: ActivatedRoute, private translate:TranslateService ) {

    translate.addLangs(["fr","en"]);
    translate.setDefaultLang("fr");//french not loading!!

    // Actually set the current language to French
    translate.use("fr").subscribe(() => {
        // Code here runs after language is set to French
        let browserlang = translate.getBrowserLang();

        console.log('browserlang', browserlang );
        console.log(`currentLang`, translate.currentLang);
    });

  }
```

From the `ng2-translate` docs:

> setDefaultLang(lang: string): Sets the default language to use as a **fallback**
>    use(lang: string): Observable: Changes the lang currently used

So the default lang is used only when setting a lang is unsuccessful.

See https://github.com/ngx-translate/core for more info.

Comment: How can i change the language?, still getting `en`

Comment: Can you try to add `console.log(translate.currentLang);`?

Comment: gives `fr` but language being translated in `en`

Comment: The translation is not applied to your app automatically - you will have to use `TranslateService`, `TranslatePipe`, or `TranslateDirective` to actually perform translation. See examples at: https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#4-use-the-service-the-pipe-or-the-directive.

Comment: already I am using `translate` pipe, let me update my code, if I put like `translate.use("fr");` loading french. but console as `en`

Comment: @3gwebtrain Have you also defined the translation as shown here: https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#3-define-the-translations ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169715/discussion-between-3gwebtrain-and-kelvin-lai).

Comment: @3gwebtrain updated code in my answer - I seem to forget to delete an extra line so it wasn't working... but it should now :)

Comment: still the `browserlang` console as `en`

Comment: but that shouldn't be an issue since browserlang can differ from your translate service's language... so is the translation in your template working?